# bootstrap DropDown dont work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-modal, jquery-3

I created a `navbar` by `DropDown` but now copy it to my new project. but  it doesn't work.
Version of jquery and bootstrap is same.

head is

```
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
```

body is

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="nav">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="nav">
        <div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active btn-info"><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> phone</a></li>
                <li><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> file</a></li>
                <li><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> fire</a></li>
                <li><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span> store</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-toggle dropdown"><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></span> Tests <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a></a> test 1</li>
                        <li><a></a> test 1</li>
                        <li><a></a> test 1</li>
                        <li><a></a> test 1</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</nav>
<div>
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

##

try this code:

```
 <a data-toggle="dropdown">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></span> Tests <span class="caret"></span></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>test 1</li>
              <li> test 1</li>
              <li> test 1</li>
              <li> test 1</li>
            </ul>
             </li>
     </ul>
```